# Topology - Fundamental group proof - Path homotopy

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

[image]

Hi,

I have been really stuck for a while on the following:

As you can see below, is part of the proof of the Fundamental group actually being a group. I am aware of the general idea behind the diagrams which 'show' the homotopy. Yet I am confused as to how you give the co-ordinates. As in, below you can see f(2s-t) is used in the left hand side, yet what method was used to know it was 2s-t. I have tried thinking of a general method, something along the lines of continous functions taking the interval [0,1/2] to [1/2,1] and then multiplying this function by t. Yet it didnt seem to work. I am asking as I am trying to find the explicit homotopy required to prove the RHS of the picture, where we need to show f is homotopic to the constant path glued with f.

Thank you for any help I have been stuck for a long time, much appreciated.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have written a short [note](http://at.yorku.ca/p/a/c/a/09.pdf) on these proofs. Check it out.